# How to Highlight Fields on Rails Validation Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, validationerror

How do you display form field highlighting for fields that fail validation errors in Rails 3.1? I know that scaffolding automatically generates the css and controller code to handle this, but I was wondering if there was a way to generate that manually. I have already implemented the string display of error messages through: @user.errors.full_messages.each...etc, but I can't get the fields to become highlighted in red. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Assuming you have an *error* class for fields in your CSS file:

```
<% if @user.errors[:name] %>
  <%= f.label :name, :class => "error" %>
<% else %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
<% end %>
```

Is this what you want?

**Extra**: [here's a section about customizing default ActiveRecord validations CSS.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#customizing-error-messages-css)

**Edit:** *(about extra ifs)*

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb

def field_class(resource, field_name)
  if resource.errors[field_name]
    return "error".html_safe
  else
    return "".html_safe
  end
end
```

And then:

```
# in your view

<%= f.label :name, :class => field_class(@user, :name) %>
<%= f.label :password, :class => field_class(@user, :password) %>
[...]
```

*(I may have make a mistake in there - I'm writing on a phone - but you get the general idea. You can code this in number of ways = infinity, so do it the way you like...)*

Comment: Thanks. That works, but that would mean I would have to do an if for each form field...

Comment: See edit. I bet you could code it even inline if you like. Or you could even override `label` itself and don't have to ever write any extra characters.

Comment: I love this bit of code and have been using it for a while now. This is fewer lines for those happy saving space... `resource.errors[field_name].present? ? "error".html_safe : "".html_safe`

Comment: There is method for this now `@user.errors.include?(:name)` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-include-3F

Answer (score 10):

Rails now have a nice trick up its sleeve..When an `error` occurs rails put a `div` with a class `.field_with_errors` around the error fields. So now you can just target that class and add styling.

To focus on the input you can do

```
.field_with_errors input{
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

this css will put a nice red line around the `input` element while `important!` will overwrite any existing styles.

Comment: Amazing! This is so simple ! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this (resource.errors[field_name].length > 0) to get it to work:

def field_class(resource, field_name)
    if resource.errors[field_name].length > 0
      return " custom_error1 ".html_safe
    else
      return "".html_safe
    end
  end

Comment: Or you can use the `present?` method: `if resource.errors[field_name].present?`