# How do I style this email_field alert box? (Rails 4, Bootstrap, JQuery)

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm using the email_field helper function in Rails in order take emails and add them to the database. The alert boxes were provided automatically - I didn't do anything beyond running the email_field function.

My question is: Can I style this alert box using CSS or is this a Javascript thing? If it's Javascript, how would I style it?

Picture attached of alert box in question:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/210bn.png]

EDIT: The other question only deals with Rails validation errors; this alert box isn't raising any validation errors from what I can tell (since the Users model that it's attached to doesn't have any validations in place).

The only relevant code that I can see is <%= f.email_field :email %>. Some research indicates that this is part of HTML5's validating forms and the display of these things is served by the browser, but I haven't found any particular way to style them (i.e. create a uniform error display across browsers.)

Comment: Do you have any code to show what you've done so far?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222408/how-to-highlight-fields-on-rails-validation-errors.

Comment: Thanks, that did it!